# bootstrap: horizontal centering and background color for image link on phone

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I saw a few solutions for horizontal centering elements in bootstrap (col-md-offset-3 and center-block) but none of them appear to work.
My code is:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paper-main">
                            <img class="desert" src="<?= get_template_directory_uri().'/resources/img/prince_-desert2.png' ?>">
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 page-arrow">
                                <div class="center-block">
                                    <?php if ( $paged > 1 ) : ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_previous_posts_page_link(); ?>"><img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri().'/resources/img/little-prince-right-arrow.png' ?>"></a>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                                <ul class="chapters-list">
                                    <?php
                                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

                                    $temp = $wp_query;
                                    $wp_query = null;
                                    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                                    $wp_query->query(['cat' => ($paged+4), 'order' => 'ASC']);
                                    $wp_query->max_num_pages = 3;
                                    ?>
                                    <?php  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>
                                                <?php the_title() ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 page-arrow">
                                <?php if ( $paged < 3 ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>"><img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri().'/resources/img/little-prince-left-arrow.png' ?>"></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
```

css:

```
    .page-arrow { padding: 0; }

.page-arrow img, .paper-pagination img { background-color: #337ab7 }
.page-arrow:hover img, .paper-pagination img:hover { background-color: #23527c }
```

I'm trying to center the pagination images.

Also, the pagination arrows are an image with a filled background.
On the computer view it works fine, but on phones there's a gap I can't close with css:
[Phone View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJES2.png)

[Regular View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCBAF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean abut wanting the arrows to be centered horizontally? Right now they appear to be spaced evenly in terms of horizontal positioning.

Did you mean that you want the arrows to be centered vertically as well? If they were both dead center horizontally then they wouldn't be able to be aligned in the same row across the page, as they are in the screenshots you posted.

If you really did just want to know how to center the arrow images  horizontally, you could try this CSS:

```css
.col-md-12 {max-width: 100%;}
.center-block img {display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paper-main">
                            <img class="desert" src="<?php  get_template_directory_uri().'/resources/img/prince_-desert2.png' ?>">
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 page-arrow">
                                <div class="center-block">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_previous_posts_page_link(); ?>"><img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/png/512/arrow-right-a.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                                <ul class="chapters-list">
                                    <?php 
                                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

                                    $temp = $wp_query;
                                    $wp_query = null;
                                    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                                    $wp_query->query(['cat' => ($paged+4), 'order' => 'ASC']);
                                    $wp_query->max_num_pages = 3;
                                    ?>
                                    <?php  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>
                                                <?php the_title() ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 page-arrow center-block">
                                <?php if ( $paged < 3 ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>"><img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/png/512/arrow-left-a.png" height="50" widht="50"></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
```

I replaced your site's arrow images with some random arrows hosted by a CDN just so something shows up.

Comment: Yes, vertically, sorry.

Comment: but thank you
what about the margin between the img and the div?